# PHP: Simple and universal way to secure uploads: how about XORing with a random number?

Tags: php, file, security, upload

I'm trying to implement a simple, universal way to allow file uploads and downloads via a php-script without having to worry about the security of my server.

There are many questions and answers dealing with this, but from what I have seen, they are mostly combinations of several methods (checking the file extension, checking the MIME-type, saving to a protected directory, changing the file name, etc.) that each have their flaws and/or vulnerabilities.

I was thinking of a php-upload-script that creates a random 4-byte-number for each uploaded file, then XORs the content of the file with it (repeating the 4 bytes as often as necessary), and finally attaches the 4 bytes to the file before saving it.

For downloading, the 4 bytes have to be cut off of the file again, the contents will be XORed with them and the result is sent to the client.

This way, I can be sure that the files I save on the server will not be executable or have any potential meaning for any application. Plus I don't need any extra database to store filenames in.

What do you think of this solution with regard to security and performance?
I am a bit concerned about the performance and required processing power on the server side, but then again XOR is generally fast and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I'm using for this now, if anyone is interested. It works for me. So far it looks like a rather foolproof solution to me. 
I'm still interested, if anyone has an opinion on this.

Upload:

```
            <?php
                $outputfilename = $_POST['filename'];
                $inputfile = $_FILES["myblob"]["tmp_name"];
                $tempfilename="temp.tmp";

                if( move_uploaded_file($inputfile, $tempfilename) ) {
                    $XORstring = random_bytes(4);

                    $tempfile=fopen($tempfilename, "r");
                    $outputfile=fopen($outputfilename, "w+");
                    flock($outputfilename, LOCK_EX);

                    fwrite($outputfilename, $XORbytes1);

                    while ( $buffer = fread($tempfile, 4) ) {
                        $buffer = $buffer ^ $XORstring;
                        fwrite($outputfilename, $buffer);
                    }

                    flock($outputfilename, LOCK_UN);

                    fclose($tempfile);
                    fclose($outputfile);

                    unlink($tempfilename);
                }

                exit(0);
            ?>
```

Download:

```
            <?php
                $inputfilename = $_POST['filename'];
                $tempfilename = "temp.tmp";

                $inputfile=fopen($inputfilename, "r");
                $tempfile=fopen($tempfilename, "w+");
                flock($tempfile, LOCK_EX);

                $XORstring = fread($inputfile, 4);

                while ( $buffer = fread($inputfile, 4) ) {
                    $buffer = $buffer ^ $XORstring;
                    fwrite($tempfile, $buffer);
                }

                flock($tempfile, LOCK_UN);

                fclose($inputfile);
                fclose($tempfile);

                readfile($tempfile);
                unlink($tempfile);

                exit(0);
            ?>
```